# Executing encrypted/secure PHP/SQL script by clicking a link within an e-mail

Tags: php, web-services, encryption, wsdl

I'm receiving e-mail from my PHP/MySQL application with certain links.
When I click on a certain link (Approve, for example) within the e-mail, I want a message to be sent back to my Application, which it'd translate into a PHP script or SQL statement to update certain fields in the database.

In order to determine which fields to update, certain user and request related information may be included in the link (user name, category, amount, etc.) but I don't want this to be seen as plain text or discovered by someone looking into the e-mail details (can it be encrypted and then decrypted by the PHP application when user Clicks back in the e-mail)

I want this to happen only if I'm clicking on the original e-mail, not if it it's a forward or reply of the original

NOTE: My Application is not SSL enabled

What components/frameworks could be used to accomplish this and ensuring a perfectly secure solution (i.e. it could be PHP web services, details on what method to use to encrypt/decrypt, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

None. There is no such thing as perfect security. And if you consider that a forward may copy each and every byte of the original, it will be tricky to react differently on links in forwarded messages.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is a decoding utility, and a secondary channel to supply an encryption key - perhaps via a text message.

Comment: I was thinking on including a UUID as part of the link in the email, which would point to a WebService that ONLY reads those UUIDs. Those UUIDs will be stored in the database and the WebService server will understand what to do for each UUID. This may mean that the WebService Client doesn't request User credentials to authenticate (to user doing the actual click on the link). Is this too insecure or even feasible?

Comment: Depends on your needs really. These kind of questions are normally for security.stackexchange.com though. This kind of scheme would normally be enough for e.g. one time, time limited discounts (where a few abused discounts don't matter much). But it would obviously not enough for a complete purchase or anything that is a significant transaction for that matter.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. In this case the e-mail I'm sending is with a reminder to execute an operation. The link will be just for user to indicate the operation has been executed and by clicking in the link, the task will be marked as closed in the database. My concern is more of whether using this kind of approach in WebServices (where no authentication is requested to User) is too unsafe or not

Answer (score 0):

what about letting your user simply reply to the email so your original text is returned. You could be relatively sure, that the user is the only person with access to this particular email- address and you could read your secret and encrypted message from the email-text.

You could let a cronjob run every x seconds, let the php- script read the message for a string like:
<SECRET_INGREDIENT>jkbgv7&%%((Nj3js8<SECRET_INGREDIENT_END>
So php looks for <SECRET_INGREDIENT> and for <SECRET_INGREDIENT_END> and decrypts the part between.